# Why does Python's slice notation go from [m,n-1]?

Tags: python

Let me preface this by saying I'm new to Python, come from Ruby, and I don't have much specific knowledge about how Python works.

For one of my current projects, I'm creating a new feature in a computational chemistry Django application that reads in PDBs and then does calculations on them. After adding my code, I was getting an error that Python can't typecast a `string` as a `float`, and looked at the library that parses the PDBs.

I was quickly confused by how Python's slice notation works. For example:

```
str = 'Hello this is Josh'
str[0:2] #=> 'He'
str[2] #=> 'l'
```

What I thought calling `str[0:2]` would result it would be `Hel`, not `He`, since index `0` to `2` is 3 big.

Is there a reason that this happens this way, and why `str[m:n]` gives from `m` to `n-1`, not from `m` to `n`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's so that:

```
str[0:2] + str[2:4] == str[0:4]
```

And

```
str[0:len(str)] == str
```

In general, it's conventional for sets of numbers to be defined this way; inclusive of the first listed number, exclusive of the second.

Esdgar Dijkstra wrote up [a fairly well known argument](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF) for both this convention, and the convention of starting array indices at 0.

Comment: Ah I see. So the slice notation doesn't treat the two numbers as an inclusive `[m,n]` range as Ruby does, but rather a `[m,n)` range, which was my major confusion.

Comment: Additionally, while you may have intuitively known (thought) that `[0:2]` was length 3, what about `[137:418]`? The advantage of Python's way, as the Dijkstra link notes, is that `n - m` is the length of the subsequence. (e.g., `[0:2]` is length `2-0=2` and `[137:418]` is length `418-137=281`)